# Reload Angularjs state from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-routing

it's possibile to reload the current state in Angularjs ($state.reload())
from jquery code?
I know it's possible to access to angular scope with:

```
angular.element("#xxx").scope()
```

but i can't access to actual $state. i need to reload it. if i use localtion.reload() of Jquery, it reload also parent controller. I want only reload child controller (from jquery)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
$state.go($state.$current, null, { reload: true });
```

Second option is, You can do `$state.reload()`

There's a bug with it sometimes not re-instantiating the controller. You can resolve that using:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true });
```

Comment: Thankyou but i need to reload state from jquery code, external to angular controller